# "Previously, we met up with x" or "Previously, we meet up with x"

Tags: grammar, past-tense

As above..

I am just wondering why so many people uses the sentence below -

> "Few weeks ago, we meet up with..."

instead of using 'met up'.

Comment: I think it is just preference.

Comment: Most people simply say "met".  The use of either "up" or "both" is superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depended, if the person is talking in past tense or present tense.

The informal definition of the [meet up with](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meet%20up%20with)
in Merriam Webster is

> : to come together with (someone) : to go to a place to be with (someone)

Following are the two examples from Merriam Webster:

> I'll meet up with you later.
>
> They met up with each other for drinks.

Comment: Hey thanks for the replu. Could you advise base on the above title/context?

Comment: @JohnLee accept the changes I have suggested. It will make your question more readable.

Comment: @JohnLee you don't have any context in your description. Which context you are talking about?

Comment: @JohnLee I can think of no context in which it would be grammatical to say, ***Previously***, *we* ***meet*** *up with*, so, without more information, it's likely you want to say ***met*** *up with*.

Answer (score 0):

This looks (from the brief sample) like an example of the **historical present** (also, **dramatic present** or **narrative present**) that is frequently used when relating stories set in the past.

From [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/historical-present):

> the present tense used to narrate past events, usually employed in English for special effect or in informal use, as in *a week ago I'm walking down the street and I see this accident*

Some people don't like this use of the resent tense even though it has been used for centuries (or even millennia). It was used by Latin writers:

> ... the historical present is very often used in Latin literature and in most modern European literatures as well as in oral everyday practice. This usage may perhaps be illustrated by an example from Latin. In Catullus's famous poem on Attis ... in the two most excited scenes of the poem, the ecstatic dance in which Attis leads the chorus of the Galli to the sanctuary of Cybele, and the concluding section where Cybele lets loose her lion and orders him to·bring Attis back into her service, the historical perfect, which is generally supposed to correspond to the Greek aorist, is replaced by the historical present: 28ff: *Thiasus repente linguis trepidantibus ULULAT. Leve tympanum REMUGIT, cava cymbala RECREPANT,* ...

From [*The So-Called Historical Present in Early Greek*, Kurt von Fritz](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00437956.1949.11659503) which then goes on to analyse the use in Early Greek.